# Flex ItemRenderer: rendering the source item of a drag

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer

When an item is being dragged from/within a list in the default implementation, it is shown as selected during the drag (and a separate item renderer, in `dragging` state, is shown as the drag image), so:

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:Label text="{data}" color.selected="0xFF0000" color.dragging="0x00FF00" />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

renders as:

[image: ListItemRenderer in normal, selected, and dragging states]

Is there a straightforward way to change the state of the source of the drag (the red, selected, "Bar") to something other than "selected" for the duration of the drag?

In the ideal, I would add `color.dragSource="0x0000FF"` to the item renderer code above, and "Bar" would be red while selected, but blue once the dragging had begun.  When the drag was complete, it would revert to red (or, if no longer selected, black).

Comment: Shouldn't a list have a way to change the visual display of the selected item?  Possibly through the use of styles.

Comment: I'm hoping for a difference between "selected" and "currently being dragged", though--is there a clear way to differentiate?

Comment: Not that I know of.. assuming the list only allows a single selection; you could tweak the selected item styles on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

What if you did an eventListener on drag start that set the selected item in the list to -1? -1 says that nothing should be selected.

Edit: added below code to support:

```
<s:List id="myList" dragStart="startDrag(event)"/>

private var dragIndex:int;

private function startDrag(e:Event):void
{
    dragIndex = myList.selectedIndex;
    myList.selectedIndex = -1;
}

private function stopDrag(e:Event):void
{
    myList.selectedIndex = dragIndex;
}
```

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to store the selected index in a var first that way on drag stop you can restore the selection.

Comment: Good call. Up voted your comment and added to above sample code.